# randomly segmentation fault on GPU/OpenCL/OpenGL code

Tags: opengl, segmentation-fault, opencl

I am working on a GPU/OpenCL NBody code. I make rendering of particles positions with OpenGL of the AMD APP SDK. When running the code, I have randomly segmentation fault.

To summarize, I have a GLWidget into which I do OpenGL rendering. Once the initial positions are generated, I render them in this GLWidget. After, I run the simulation and at every step I compute the next positions and show them in the GLwidget. My problem is that sometimes, if I click on the "generate Initial Conditions" button of parameters GUI while the simulation is running, I have a segmentation fault :

here's the backtrace :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff4a46cd7 in memcpy () from /lib/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff4a46cd7 in memcpy () from /lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007fffeda2da64 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#2  0x00007fffedbba74a in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#3  0x00007fffedbba9af in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#4  0x00007fffed9c56e4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#5  0x00007fffed17371d in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/fglrx_dri.so
#6  0x000000000040b185 in GLWidget::createVBO() ()
#7  0x000000000040b3c9 in GLWidget::draw() ()
#8  0x000000000040c36d in GLWidget::processCurrent() ()
...
```

Here's the `createVBO` routine :

```
void GLWidget::createVBO()
{   
  GLuint vbo;
  int memSize = sizeof(cl_double4) * 4 * Galaxy->getNumParticles();
  glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, memSize, Galaxy->pos, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
```

The segfault occurs at `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, memSize, Galaxy->pos, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);`

I don't understand why this happens. When I push on the "generate IC" button, I delete the allocated `Galaxy->pos` array and create a new one.

Here's what I do in the "generate IC" routine :

```
  //Clean Galaxy already existing 
  if (parent->widget_2->isGalaxyExist)
  { 
    if (parent->widget_2->animation)
      parent->resetSimu();
    parent->widget_2->Galaxy->cleanup();
  }
```

with `cleanup` routine (where I delete `pos` array) :

```
int NBody::cleanup()
{
  if (glEvent)
    clReleaseEvent(glEvent);

  // Releases OpenCL resources (Context, Memory etc.)
  cl_int status;

  if (hasRunKernel)
  {
  status = clFinish(commandQueue);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clFinish failed.(commandQueue)");

  status = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clReleaseKernel failed.(kernel)");

  status = clReleaseProgram(program);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clReleaseProgram failed.(program)");

  status = clReleaseMemObject(currPos);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clReleaseMemObject failed.(currPos)");

  status = clReleaseMemObject(currVel);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clReleaseMemObject failed.(currVel)");

  status = clReleaseMemObject(newPos);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clReleaseMemObject failed.(newPos)");

  status = clReleaseMemObject(newVel);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clReleaseMemObject failed.(newVel)");

  status = clReleaseCommandQueue(commandQueue);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clReleaseCommandQueue failed.(commandQueue)");

  status = clReleaseContext(context);
  CHECK_OPENCL_ERROR(status, "clReleaseContext failed.(context)");

  hasRunKernel = false;
  }

  // Release program resources 
  delete [] pos;
  delete [] vel;
  delete [] initPos;
  delete [] initVel;
  delete [] devices;
  // Delete current instance
  delete this;

  return NBODY_SUCCESS;
}
```

At first sight, could you see what's wrong or give me a clue on this segfault. the most annoying is that error happens randomly, not at every execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this calculation correct?

```
int memSize = sizeof(cl_double4) * 4 * Galaxy->getNumParticles();
```

In particular " * 4": sizeof(cl_double4) will already take account the four elements of the vector.

Answer (score 1):

Crashes like this indicate an out-of-bounds access in the driver code called through the `glBufferData` OpenGL API function. Check that the parameters passed to `glBufferData` are correct, i.e. that the length given to glBufferData to read is within the bounds of the memory passed as data parameter.